# Alternative to eval when reading json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, function, class

I have a class to parse data from some online dictionaries, it reads info about word from json and then executes methods as json tells to.
An example of json:

```
{
"functions": [
    {
        "name": "find_translations",
        "properties": {
            "only_first": false
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "find_synonyms",
        "properties": {
             "number": 5
        }
],
"word": "to exuberate",
"language": "angielski",
"target_language": "polski",
"collection": "default"
}
```

So, I have a class with methods find_translations and find_synonyms. And __init __ is reading the json, and I want to execute functions *with parameters* as in json.
I could do a bunch of ifs, but it isn't scalable, I guess. I could do eval(), but it is a vulnerability. What do I do? Can I create something like a dictionary with functions?

EDIT:

Here's my class (simplified):

```
class Parser:
  def __init__(self, path):
    ...
    # reads data from json
    ...

    # my problem: I need to launch methods from this class
    # that were mentioned in json. In case from example, I'd launch
    self.find_translations(self)
    self.find_synonyms(self)
    # it is an example, so without parameters


def find_translations(self):
    # do something

def find_synonyms(self):
    # do something

def find_usage(self):
    # do something
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question, but maybe you are searching for `**kwargs`? Here a reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3394898/2319299

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about this. It is solving my problem with passing arguments from json, but I still need to execute functions mentioned in json

Comment: Ah! that was not clear... No you need to use some eval-like function, and you need to bound it very well. Make a "white" list of allowed functions and check that you run only json functions that are on that list. I don't have a safer method in mind right now... hope in someone with a better idea...

Comment: Thanks! I edited my question. Eval came to my mind also, but I wasn't sure if it is a good idea, if nobody will post an idea better than yours, I will use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the getattr function to call a particular method of class like this:-

```
getattr(Parser, function_name_here)(arguments_here)
```

I think This was what you were asking for? I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, You can use self in place of Parser.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ast.literal_eval` as a safer alternative to `eval`:

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> `ast.literal_eval`: Safely evaluate an expression node or a string
>   containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node
>   provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures:
>   strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and
>   `None`.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python
>   values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values
>   oneself. It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex
>   expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.